# TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in keras tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I'm writing a custom loss function using `keras.layers.Layer`. Here is the code:

```
class SIAMESE_LOSS(Layer):
    def __init__(self, index, **kwargs):
        super(SIAMESE_LOSS, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.index = index

    @staticmethod
    def mmd_loss(source_samples, target_samples, weights=1):
        return mmd(source_samples, target_samples, weights)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        mmd_loss = self.mmd_loss(inputs[0], inputs[1])

        self.add_loss(mmd_loss, inputs=True)
        self.add_metric(mmd_loss, aggregation='mean', name='MMD_'+str(self.index))

        return inputs
```

But if I call it, with  `[x2, x3] = SIAMESE_LOSS(index=1, name='siamese_loss_1')(x2, x3)`, an error occurs:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Is it because it's illegal to write `self.index` into the call function? If so, how can I define different metric names for different layers?

Comment: `self` is the first argument, `x2` passed as `inputs` and that's all, no positional arguments left for `x3`.  `**kwargs` are keyword arguments.

Comment: that should make it work `def call(self, *inputs, **kwargs):`

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov Thanks a lot! As you said I forgot to include x2, x3 in a list.